# Visual Studio Database project, Schema in file name not appearing

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, database-project

Been looking for an answer to this for about an hour now and cant seem to find anything which helps me.

I'm creating a new database project of `Adventure Works` (Just as a test for myself) and the `Schema names` don't seem to be copying over. I have selected the option to **include schema name in file name**, but this still does nothing.

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. See image below (Database on the left is the one i'm copying and you can see the schema, but you cannot see it on the right?)

[image]

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: I think this might actually be a bug in SSDT. I seem to recall coming across something similar recently. Is it even putting them in the right schema folders? That could be something to write up @ the MS Connect site.

Answer (score 4):

Once you create empty "SQL Server Database Project", just before importing Database open up project properties (Project -> AdventureWorks Properties...):
[Visual Studio Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpLcL.png)

and below Default schema input select "Include schema name in file name":
[Visual Studio Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZFyM.png)